# Different text colors in navigation view for each items?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-navigationview

I am using Navigation View in android studio to create a navigation drawer in my app. In the navigation drawer, I want one item to be colored in green, one in red and others in black (just like the one in the screenshot below). However, I can't seem to find the solution to this. I know I can change the color of all the items using 'itemTextColor' in XML but that's not what I want to do.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried inside your menu.xml on whichever items you need adding `android:textColor: "[YOUR_COLOR_HERE]"`

Comment: @DavidKroukamp There is no `android:textColor` attribute in menu.xml item tags

Comment: Check my answer, its not easy to do this in XML for a single menu item in `NavigationView`, you will have to do it in the code.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems it not as easy to change specific items colours, its either all or nothing (via `app:itemIconTint` and `app:itemTextColor` on the `com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView`), but it seems you can do something like this (I did it in Java as you never mentioned if you were using *Kotlin* or *Java*):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // .. other code

    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    // .. other code

    int menuItemPosition = 0; // the position of the menu item in NavigationView you want to change the color of
    MenuItem menuItem = navigationView.getMenu().getItem(menuItemPosition);
    this.changeMenuItemColor(menuItem, Color.RED);
}


private void changeMenuItemColor(MenuItem menuItem, @ColorInt int color) {
    SpannableString coloredMenuItemTitle = new SpannableString(menuItem.getTitle());
    coloredMenuItemTitle.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, coloredMenuItemTitle.length(), 0);
    menuItem.setTitle(coloredMenuItemTitle);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I did manage to change the text color using this. However, it still doesn't change the icon tint. Can you tell me how I can do that too?

Comment: Doesnt seem possible mate, techincally they are all supposed to share the same colours, thats the way the NavigationView was built, this "hack" for changing the text color is just possible because of how the text is rendered in the presenter, but it looks like it overrides all tints applied no matter what you set programmatically (besides in the XML, but that changes all items not just 1 or 2 items)